# Datatables get filtered data not working and copy to second table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to get filtered data from one table to copy to another table. Both are using data tables. but when i tried to use the

```
 oriTable._('tr', {filter:'applied'});
```

i got the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in the console.
I am using datatables 1.10.1. Im dont know why is this happening. I initialize the datatables like this. before the line to get the filtered data.

```
    var oriTable = $('#originalList').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [4,5],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        },
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
        ]
    });
```

i tried using this one

```
var rows = oriTable.$('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
```

but when i use append to append to the second table like this

```
            $("#selectedList").find("tbody").html('');
            $("#selectedList").find("tbody").append(rows);
            selTable = $('#selectedList').DataTable({
                "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [4,5],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }]
             });
```

i will get

[image]

then i tried to use like this

```
            $("#selectedList").find("tbody").html('');
            $("#selectedList").find("tbody").append(rows);

            selTable
                .order( [ 1, 'asc' ] )
                .draw(false);
```

but this one the selTable did not show the rows.
this is how the selTable initialize.

```
    var selTable = $('#selectedList').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [4,5],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        },
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }]
    });
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in data tables 1.10.1. This

```
 oriTable._('tr', {filter:'applied'});
```

has become this

```
 oriTable.rows({filter:'applied'});
```

with this, i copy to second table with same amount of column, like this

```
var rows = oriTable.rows({filter:'applied'});
var rowsData = rows.data();
rows.remove().draw();

selTable.rows.add(rowsData).draw();
```